# gitlab-runner unable to use `pyenv, pip, ...`

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am in the Debian9. And `sudo su` to become `root` user. After that I run the command `gitlab-runner register`. But for some reasons. I got the isolated environment not the same like when I login to the server over ssh

```
gitlab-runner --version
Version:      10.8.0
Git revision: 079aad9e
Git branch:
GO version:   go1.8.7
Built:        2018-05-22T03:24:56+00:00
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

When I put `env` in the `before_script` I found the different environment.
Then I put `source ~/.bashrc` to it. Also does not make any change.
How to let `shell` runner use my normal login user environement?

**Update:**
When I execute `env` (by putting in `before_script`) I got this output

```
$ env
CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH=linux/amd64
CI_COMMIT_TITLE=add config
CI_JOB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CI_BUILD_REF_NAME=master
CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CI_RUNNER_TAGS=provider, oauth, mp
CI_SHARED_ENVIRONMENT=true
CI_JOB_NAME=test
CI_SERVER_VERSION=10.8.4
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.local
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GITLAB_CI=true
CI_SERVER_REVISION=2268d0c
CI_PROJECT_VISIBILITY=private
OLDPWD=/home/gitlab-runner
INVOCATION_ID=7dd516612949410c8ca8e4e59696f9fd
CI_COMMIT_SHA=9030892858b5ca92c7b36a81f573f187e6d14090
CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE=add config

CI_BUILD_STAGE=test
CI_PROJECT_URL=https://mbx-git.magicboxasia.com/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider
CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=master
CI_SERVER_NAME=GitLab
CI_RUNNER_VERSION=10.8.0
CI_BUILD_NAME=test
CI=true
XDG_SESSION_ID=c5
CI_REGISTRY_USER=gitlab-ci-token
USER=gitlab-runner
CI_PROJECT_ID=96
CI_PIPELINE_ID=4399
CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION=
PWD=/home/gitlab-runner/builds/f304ea76/0/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider
GITLAB_FEATURES=
HOME=/home/gitlab-runner
JOURNAL_STREAM=8:19161
CI_REGISTRY=docker-registry.magicboxasia.com
CI_BUILD_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CI_BUILD_ID=5514
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
GITLAB_USER_NAME=Sarit Ritwirune
CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG=sarit-mhu-ped-oauth-provider
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/mp_oauth_provider
POSTGRES_DB=poinkdb
GITLAB_USER_EMAIL=sarit@magicboxasia.com
CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=master
CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=docker-registry.magicboxasia.com/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider
CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE=/home/gitlab-runner/builds/f304ea76/0/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
CI_RUNNER_ID=42
CI_SERVER=yes
CI_JOB_ID=5514
CI_REPOSITORY_URL=https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@mbx-git.magicboxasia.com/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider.git
MAIL=/var/mail/gitlab-runner
SHELL=/bin/bash
GITLAB_USER_LOGIN=sarit
CI_RUNNER_REVISION=079aad9e
CI_CONFIG_PATH=.gitlab-ci.yml
CI_PROJECT_NAME=mhu_ped_oauth_provider
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
SHLVL=2
CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=MP OAuth Provider
CI_PROJECT_PATH=sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider
LOGNAME=gitlab-runner
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/999
GITLAB_USER_ID=39
CI_BUILD_BEFORE_SHA=e36e718d09f89095972ddf60ebf1fc1931282ae4
CI_BUILD_REF=9030892858b5ca92c7b36a81f573f187e6d14090
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=push
CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE=sarit
CI_PROJECT_DIR=/home/gitlab-runner/builds/f304ea76/0/sarit/mhu_ped_oauth_provider
CI_JOB_STAGE=test
CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG=master
_=/usr/bin/env
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: How have you set up the gitlab-runner? If you've set the runner up using `sudo`, it would have created a separate `gitlab-runner` account and hence would use a different user environment.

Comment: I have separate `gitlab-runner`. But the problem is not there. The problem is when I let it run `python, pip, pyenv, ... ` it returns command not found.

Comment: Is `python, pip, pyenv` installed globally? Have you tried becoming the `gitlab-runner` and accessing the commands there?

Comment: @Rekovni Sure. I have set it already. This is just happen with `10.8.0` by previous project `10.7.0` does not has this problem. In worst case I will use `docker` runner instead of `shell` runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best practice or not, but I directly set the `PATH` by this in order to let the `gitlab-runner` use same as I do when `ssh` remote to server. But at least it works.

```
variables:
    PATH: "/home/gitlab-runner/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/gitlab-runner/.pyenv/shims:/home/gitlab-runner/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to setting variables directly in gitlab-ci ...

```
job: 
  variables:
    MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE:my_variable
```

Better place an environment file in your project's main directory within e.g a file .ci/env.
In project directory (same level as .gitlab-ci.yml):

```
$ mkdir .ci
$ vi .ci/env
```

Then, in `.gitlab-ci.yml` copy the file into build context:

```
before_script:
  - . .ci/env
```

In there you can place your custom or modified variables as in:

#### Any custom variables

```
export MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE=my_variable
```

#### Pyenv and pipenv context variables:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH=/home/gitlab-runner/.pyenv/shims:/home/gitlab-runner/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/shims/python"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try your answer next time with new project.